# userdefaults not saving button state

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning UserDefaults, and I am using UserDefaults to store button state in them and use them on re-launching application.

My viewController has two button on which click the button image is changed.
Function which represents button targets:

```
extension DetailViewController{
@objc func checkButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    
   detailViewModel?.watchedButtonPressed(sender: sender)
   setupButton(sender: sender, button: .check)
}

@objc func favoriteButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    
    detailViewModel?.favoriteButtonPressed(sender: sender)
    setupButton(sender: sender, button: .favorite)
}
}
```

Functions which are changing buttons states and save state value in UserDefault.

```
func watchedButtonPressed(sender: UIButton){
    
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(sender.isSelected, forKey: "mvvmCheck\(movieIndex ?? 0)")  
}

func favoriteButtonPressed(sender: UIButton){

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(sender.isSelected, forKey: "mvvmFavorite\(movieIndex ?? 0)") 
}
```

Function which change button image when its clicked:

```
func setupButton(sender: UIButton, button: buttonType){
    switch button {
    case .favorite:
        sender.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star"), for: .normal)
        sender.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"), for: .selected)
    case .check:
        sender.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.seal"), for: .normal)
        sender.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.seal.fill"), for: .selected)
    }
}
```

Function to setup buttons images when launching application:

```
func setupButtons(){

buttonChecked.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "mvvmCheck\(detailViewModel?.movieIndex ?? 0)")
buttonFavorite.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "mvvmFavorite\(detailViewModel?.movieIndex ?? 0)")
setupButton(sender: buttonChecked, button: .check)
setupButton(sender: buttonFavorite, button: .favorite)

}
```

But my values are not stored well when I am clicking (on app re-launch some buttons dont have valid picture (value) and some have)
Should I use button tags to achieve this? Is problem if I am sending *sender* value through functions calls?

Comment: Storing this sort of information in UserDefaults is fragile. What happens if the array of movies changes, and the indexes aren't the same across launches of the app?, the wrong favourites will be selected. You should really look at a proper local storage mechanism for this that stores whether the movie is favourited or not in the same place as the movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't think you should be using UserDefaults to store this information the problem is the way you are setting the value to UserDefaults.

You are using

```swift
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(...
```

If you command click on `setValue` in Xcode, you'll see that you are taken to the function in `Foundation.NSKeyValueCoding`. You should instead be using the correct UserDefaults function

```swift
UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isSelected, ...
```

Which properly encodes the type.